# Show a AlertDialog from a ContextMenu

Tags: android, dialog, contextmenu, android-alertdialog

I have a ContextMenu in a ListView and it has the option of DELETE an item from the ListView.
So when user selecte DELETE from the ContextMenu I would like to show an AlertDialog asking for confirmation of this delete.

But when AlertDialog.show() is called inside of onMenuItemSelected(..) it do not shows the Dialog. This dialog will only be showed after the "return true" of onMenuItemSeletect(..)

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    //0: for OPEN of R.array.context_menu_categories
    case 0:

        break;

    //2: DELETE
    case 2:

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

         // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Delete...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this?");


        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // User pressed No button. Write Logic Here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

        break;

    default:
    break;
}

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by your last sentence: "This dialog will only be showed after the "retun true" of onMenuItemSeletect(..)"?

Comment: When the onMenuItemSelected finishs with the "return true;"; then the context menu will hide and then the dialog will appear.

Comment: I found the "solution"... And it was a wrong way of implementation.

After the dialog.show(); so it was the end of the context menu, nothing else I should implement after it, and the correct way to do was to implement everything on alertDialog.setPositiveButton or NegativeButton.

So it is working with the confirmation dialog after click on Delete item.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Android works.  Graphical elements don't appear until the app redraws itself, which happens in the Android event loop.  To get back to the event loop, you have to exit the function Android called.  There is no way to make it appear before this function returns.

Comment: Gabe, how can I end the function (in the case onMenuItemSelected) and also show the dialog? I don't know how to do that...